# iOS external subscriptions

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Since a couple of days I'm looking to integrate In App Purchases in my iOS Swift app (Auto renewable subscriptions). With succes: I can make a test purchase. I've experience with this kind of subscriptions in Android, but in iOS it's a disaster. It's a real hassle to check the state of an auto renewing subscription. You can work with receipts, but there are no good tutorials on the internet how to implement this in a good way in Swift. Once a user purchased an auto renewing subscription, you want to check sometimes if the subscription is cancelled or not.

My question: is it allowed to let users make a purchase on my website, and when they login with their account in the iOS-app, I check if he/she purchased a subscription on the website? SI replace the payment system to my website and let users login in the app to check if they have a subscription?

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to do that. However, and this is a big one, you can't direct users from the app to your website to purchase a subscription. I'm pretty sure there are plenty of resources on how to implement what you need, and if it's in ObjC, it shouldn't be hard to convert the code.

Comment: Hi Emilio, thanks for your reply. Believe me, there is no good tutorial about how to check the status of an auto renewing subscription. It's very frustrating Apple don't have an API to query the status of a subscription, like in Android.